# weird output using strncpy and strncat

Tags: c, string, strncpy, string.h

I want to write a program that gets the first half of a string 'ch1' and puts it in a string 'ch3' then gets the first half of another string 'ch2' and concatenates it in 'ch3' "puts is in the end of ch3" but when I execute it, it gives me weird output for ch3 ..
for example :

```
ch1 ="123"
ch2 ="azertyuiop"
```

the result :
ch3 ="1<3rdweirdletter>azert"

This is my code :

```
int main()
{ 
char ch1[200],ch2[200],ch3[200]; 

puts("give 'ch1' ");
gets(ch1);
puts("give 'ch2' ");
gets(ch2);

strncpy(ch3,ch1, strlen(ch1)/2 );
strncat(ch3,ch2, strlen(ch2)/2 );

printf("a half \"%s\" + a half \"%s\" gives \"%s\"",ch1,ch2,ch3);

return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate if someone helps me.
Thanks

Comment: `man strncpy`: *[...] Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src,
       the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.*

Comment: would you please explain a bit more..
Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Don't use `gets`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/4996248

Comment: I did change gets with scanf("%s",<variable>);
still the problem persists

Comment: The problem is that `strncpy` doesn't automatically terminate the string with `'\0'`. You would need to terminate it manually. Your `ch3` isn't null-terminated.

Comment: @SamiBenAbderazak `scanf` `%s` has exactly the same problem as `gets`. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either initialize `ch3[]` to be all zeroes: `char ch3[200] = { 0 };`
Or you can manually place the null-terminator (the character `'\0'`) on `ch3` after copying the first half of `ch1` to it:

```
strncpy(ch3, ch1, strlen(ch1) / 2);
ch3[strlen(ch1)/2] = '\0';
strncat(ch3, ch2, strlen(ch2) / 2);
```

This is needed because strings in C need to be null-terminated (meaning you need a value of 0 after the last character of the string to mark the end of the string). The function `strncpy(s, ct, n)` only pads with zeroes if `ct` has less characters than `n` (not your case), therefore, if you don't add the null character manually, `strncat` will think that `ch3` is much longer. It will search for the first zero in memory after `ch3`'s start and only there it will concatenate what you wanted. That's where those weird characters come from.